# comparing tables of two different database simultaneously for any difference in data

Tags: c++, mysql

i have doing some search regarding mysql connector documentation  about running queries related to 2 tables on 2 different database but i didnt find anything useful till now.One thing i vaguely got was about getting view from it and then it would act as tables.But if i am going to access to different connections of the two databases,how can i achieve that simultaneously.What i really want to do via c++ mysql connector is :-

```
  select client_id from log_event where test_id='abc'(suppose from  database client)
  select client_id from client_log_eventwhere test_id='abc'(suppose from database server)
```

then when i get both of these resultsets i want to compare both of their resultset for any difference.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use the federated Storage Engine **"The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables."** see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: but how do i use it in c++ for querying

Comment: what i mean i i want to access two tables as the above two queries in the two different datbase and compare them simultaneously